# Elevation above sea level in sql server using Latitude and Longitude Information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have thousands of latitude and longitude information in a table in sql sever
Using a pair of lattitude and Longitude is it possible to get elevation information in a column in sql server?

Comment: You cannot calculate elevation from lat and long. That's like having x, y and wanting to know y. Or do you mean you need a database telling you the elevation at a certain location?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use ALTER TABLE and add a column for elevation.   Then populate it.